# Setting local storage in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm using the following code to set local storage in a Chrome extension.

```
localStorage.setItem('userkey','123');

/* I've also tried this:
chrome.storage.sync.set({'userkey': 123}, function() {
          // Notify that we saved.
          message('Settings saved');
        });
*/
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Shopaholic",
  "description": "All the latest sale items from your favourite clothes shops right on your home screen",
  "version": "1.0",

  "chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "index.html"
  },

"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/index.html"],
      "css": ["css/style.css"],
      "js": ["js/jquery.min.js"]

    }
  ],

 "options_page": "options.html",

"permissions": [
          "storage"
        ]
}
```

However, I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property
>   from 'Window': The document is sandboxed and lacks the
>   'allow-same-origin' flag.

If I use the commented out code above, I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sync' of undefined

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Are you overriding the newtab with a HTML doc and then injecting a content script into that HTML doc? Why not just include the content script files directly in the HTML markup like normal? Can you be more specific about where/what context you are interacting with localStorage?

Comment: As you can see from my manifest.json, I'm overriding the new tab page with a file called index.html. I'm trying to use localStorage as part of a login script to store a user key that can be checked for to see if a user is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Read this - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Basically, its a  web application security model concept.

So, to avoid this u need to disable the same origin policy on google chrome

So, if on desktop, open chrome from command line with this command

```
chrome.exe --disable-web-security
```

and then run your script, it shouldn't give this error then!

Comment: Thanks, is there not a way to get round this in `manifest.json` permissions? Otherwise every user of the extension will have to disable the same origin policy in the command line.

Comment: You can add this to manifest -- "permissions": [ "http://yourdomain.com", "storage" ]

Comment: What will my domain be? I tried index.html but it didn't change anything.

Comment: if you are hosting it locally then "localhost"

Comment: add something like "permissions": ["localhost"]

Comment: Thanks, I have `"permissions": ["localahost", "storage" ]`, but still getting this error.

Comment: you have a spelling mistake

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, error still thrown with correct spelling

Comment: Can u tell me the url u type in the browser? And also what url do you send your request to when u get this error?

Comment: This is a Chrome extension so I don't type anything in the browser - it's a replacement for my new tab page.

Comment: By the way, just to check if local storage is at all supported or not use this /* Checks if HTML5 File Storage is supported or not */
function dataStoreSupported() {
    return (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined" && window.localStorage);
}